# How to search columns for a specific value and move the target row to the top?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to search column E for a cell starting with "X". I then want to move that entire row up to the top.

This is what I've created so far, using IndexOf:

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Today = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Today");

  var TodayList = Today.getRange('E:E').getValues();

  var i = TodayList.indexOf("X", 0);  
  Today.moveRows(Today.getRow(i), 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

In the case of Array.prototype.indexOf(), the values cannot be directly checked from the 2-dimensional array. But, in your situation, I thought that the 1st character can be directly checked using the index as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Today = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Today");
  var TodayList = Today.getRange('E1:E' + Today.getLastRow()).getValues();
  TodayList.forEach(([e], i) => {
    if (e[0] == "X") {
      var row = i + 1;
      Today.moveRows(Today.getRange(`${row}:${row}`), 1);
    }
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from column "E". And, each cell value is checked from the retrieved values. When the 1st character of the cell value is "X", the row is moved to the 1st row.
- In this modification, the lower rows are moved to the upper row. If you want to do this with the reverse, please modify it as follows.

  - From

    ```
      TodayList.forEach(([e], i) => {
        if (e[0] == "X") {
          var row = i + 1;
          Today.moveRows(Today.getRange(`${row}:${row}`), 1);
        }
      });
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var len = TodayList.length;
      var offset = 0;
      TodayList.reverse().forEach(([e], i) => {
        if (e[0] == "X") {
          var row = len - i + offset;
          Today.moveRows(Today.getRange(`${row}:${row}`), 1);
          offset++;
        }
      });
    ```

#### References:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [moveRows(rowSpec, destinationIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#moverowsrowspec,-destinationindex)

Comment: This is great! However, how do I get it to work if I want to identify a cell starting with "XYZ" rather than just "X"?

Comment: @Nagaram92 Thank you for your response. I'm glad your new issue was also resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Thank you very much! That works perfectly. I have marked as solved.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I have a follow up. The /^X|^XYZ/.test(e[0]) method is almost what I need, however it moves all entries starting with "X" to the top. How do I move only the rows that have "XYZ" in them?

Comment: @Nagaram92 About your new question of `The /^X|^XYZ/.test(e[0]) method is almost what I need, however it moves all entries starting with "X" to the top. How do I move only the rows that have "XYZ" in them?`, I would like to support you. But your new question is different from this question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: no worries! I have made another post as you've suggested. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72504423/how-to-search-columns-for-a-specific-cell-value-and-move-the-target-row-to-the-t

Comment: @Nagaram92 Thank you for your response. I have to apologize. I saw your new question, now, I noticed that my proposed modification was not correct. So, I showed the modified script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize, again.

Answer (score -1):

#### Find X rows and move to top

```
function funko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName("Today");
  const tvs = tsh.getRange(1, 1, tsh.getLastRow(), tsh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let a = [];
  let d = 0;
  tvs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (r[4] == "X") {
      a.push(r)
      tsh.deleteRow(i + 1 - d++);
    }
  });
  tsh.insertRowsBefore(1,a.length)
  a.reverse();
  tsh.getRange(1,1,a.length,a[0].length).setValues(a);
}
```