# How to search columns for a specific cell value and move the target row to the top?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using google sheets appscript, I am trying to search column E for a cell starting with "XYZ", I then want to move that entire row up to the top.

This is what I've created so far:

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Today = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Today");

  var TodayList = Today.getRange('E:E').getValues();

  TodayList.forEach(([e], i) => {
    if (/^X|^XYZ/.test(e[0])) {
      var row = i + 1;
      Today.moveRows(Today.getRange(`${row}:${row}`), 6);
    }
  });
```

However this will move all entries that start with "X" to the top too. I want to just move entries that start with "XYZ".

Credit to user @Tanaike for helping me up to this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if (/^X|^XYZ/.test(e[0])) {
```

#### To:

```
if (/^XYZ/.test(e)) {
```

or

```
if (e.slice(0, 3) == "XYZ") {
```

#### Note:

- In your script, `e` of `TodayList.forEach(([e], i) => {` is the cell value. And, `e[0]` is the top character of the cell value. By this, `/^X|^XYZ/.test(e[0])` is always `false`. This is the reason of your issue. And, this was my miscopied. So, in order to check the cell value, I modified `e[0]` to `e`.
- For example, if you want to check the rows of both top letters of `XYZ` and `X`, you can use `if (/^X|^XYZ/.test(e)) {`

#### Reference:

- [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)
- [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for explaining that to me - it makes a lot more sense now. Thanks again Tanaike!

Comment: @Nagaram92 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

#### Move to top

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let a = [];
  let d = 0;
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (~r[4].toString().indexOf("xyz") || ~r[4].toString().indexOf("xy")) {
      a.push(r);
      sh.deleteRow(i + 1 - d++);
    }
  });
 if(a) {
    sh.insertRowsBefore(1, a.length);
    sh.getRange(1, 1, a.length, a[0].length).setValues(a);
 }
}
```

#### You can do it this way as well

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let a = [];
  let d = 0;
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (r[4].toString().match(/xyz|xy/g)) {
      a.push(r);
      sh.deleteRow(i + 1 - d++);
    }
  });
  if (a) {
    sh.insertRowsBefore(1, a.length);
    sh.getRange(1, 1, a.length, a[0].length).setValues(a)
  }
}
```